# How to add and remove a class name from a link when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I want to toggle the visibility of 2 links (`send_email` and `email_sent`) in a table in my rails app. Both links are within the same cell.

```
<table >
<% @applications.each do |application| %>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <a href="mailto:grant@example.com" class="send_email">Invite for an interview</a>

   <a href="" class="email_sent hidden">Undo</a>
  </td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

In my css I have

```
.hidden{display: none;}
```

Here is my javascript

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
 $(function(){
  $('.send_email > a').click(function(){
   // add the hidden class to send_email
   // remove the hidden class from the next email_sent link
  });
  $('.email_sent > a').click(function(){
   // add the hidden class to email_sent
   // remove the hidden class from the previous sent_email link
  });
 });
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can just use `.hide()` and `.show()`, why bother with classes?

Comment: You're right. My js sucks. How do you identify the 'sent_email' link to show?

Comment: Use `.next()` and `.prev()`

Comment: Thanks. All sorted now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. `$('.send_email > a')` means you have `send_email` class to the parent element of the anchor. `$('a.send_email')` is the right way to select the anchor with the class.

I would use `hide()`, `show()` like this:

```
$('a.send_email').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $('.email_sent').show();
});

$('a.email_sent').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $('.send_email').show();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the `removeClass()` and `addClass()` from jQuery.

[Remove Class docs.](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

[Add Class docs.](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)